# Powershell, I do input a list gather data and output that whole list into one CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I am creating a script that reads a list of computer names and collects data from security event logs about who is on the computer, how long they have been on for, and how long it has been since the computer has restarted. I have it working except that it does not output all the data into one CSV. I just receive one CSV file with one computer name.

```
function Get-KioskInfo {

    param (

        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True,Position=0)]
        [Alias('PSComputerName','DNSHostName','CN','Hostname')]

        [string]
        $ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        )
        #PARAM
        $User = try {(Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerName Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty username).trimstart("NG\")} catch {Write-Output "User not detected";break}
        $BootStart = ((get-date) - (Get-CimInstance win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $ComputerName).LastBootUpTime).Days
        
        #These variables are for the DATE & Time calculation
        If ($user -NE $null) 
            { Write-Verbose 1
            # Do something
            $Date1 = Get-date
            Write-Verbose 2
            $SP = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $ComputerName -FilterHashTable @{LogName = "Security";ID="5379";Data=$User; StartTime=((Get-Date).AddDays(-1))}
            Write-Verbose 3
            $Date2 =($SP | select -first 1).timecreated
            Write-Verbose 4
            $USERLOGTIME = ($Date1-$Date2).hours.tostring("N2")
            Write-Verbose 5
            }
        else{Write-Output "No user";break}
        Write-Verbose 6



        #Rename-Computer -ComputerName "Srv01" -NewName "Server001" -DomainCredential Domain01\Admin01 -Force ------ Rename script for computers if it is needed.
        #$computers = Get-Content C:\Users\jaycbee\Desktop\kiosknames.txt ------ To load kiosk list
        #foreach ($c in $computers) {start-job -Name $c -ScriptBlock ${Function:get-kioskinfo} -ArgumentList $c} for learning how to do a foreach script
        


Write "Computer Name: $Computername"
Write "---USER---"
Write "Name:          $User"
Write "Log in Time    $USERLOGTIME"
Write "Boot start     $BootStart days ago"

$ComputerName | ForEach-Object   {

    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $ComputerName -Count 1 -Quiet)
        {

        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName {




}      

  } # Offline Check

    else 
        { 
            Write-Host "Computer is Unreachable or Offline" -ForegroundColor Gray 
        }    


} # Foreach

$Continue = Read-Host "WARNING! This will READ LIST of computers in \\ou\ouor-groups\Desktop_Support\SD\Kiosks\kiosknames.txt Type CONTINUE to proceed."
if ($Continue -eq "CONTINUE")
  {
        $Computers = Get-Content '\\ou\ouor-groups\Desktop Support\SD\Kiosks\kiosknames.txt'
        foreach ($C in $Computers) {start-job -Name $c -ScriptBlock ${Function:get-kioskinfo} -ArgumentList $c
        }
        }

[pscustomobject]@{ Name = $ComputerName ; User = $User ; "User Log in time in hours" = $USERLOGTIME;"BootStart days ago" = $BootStart} | export-csv -path "\\ou\ouor-groups\Desktop Support\SD\Kiosks\test45$ComputerName.csv" -Append

} #Function

#For each-computer | do this at this location,
```

Comment: I see `Start-Job`, I don't see `Wait-Job` or `Receive-Job`. I wonder how this sorcery works.

Comment: Well, PowerShell is doing/providing what you are asking for. The PSCustomObject and Export -Csv is in the wrong place. It needs to be in the ForLoop. See my refactor below. I removed all the Write-Versose stuff because I just did not understand why you were doing that. Output to the screen is the PowerShell default. The other way to see screen results as your code runs is using PowerShells' variable squeezing, which assigns results to the variable and outputs to the screen at the same time; which is what I am doing in the refactor.

Comment: It is not a requirement. It's just a choice. I find it useful in dev/test runs and sometimes in production code if I plan to out result always. So, unless you have specific needs or coding style, they are not really needed. I removed the comments because I have a firm belief in, `Do not comment the obvious and if y0u have comments, that is what `Comment-based Help` is for. Your code should be 100% self-explanatory and easy to read for the most novice of folks who'd see/need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These didn't help me with my solution, but you were right about the start-jobs. I have to rework the entire script in order to get the correct info.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment. I too wonder why the use of jobs for this use case. Unless you are doing this on hundreds of computers, thus needing parallel processing.

This refactor/formatting is just my way of making sense of what you posted. I'm old, and crowded code just really hurts my eyes.  ***;-}*** Yet, code the way you like of course. ***;-}***

I do not have an environment to test this, but give it a shot.

```
function Get-KioskInfo 
{
    param 
    (
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True,Position = 0)]

        [Alias(
            'PSComputerName',
            'DNSHostName',
            'CN',
            'Hostname'
        )]
    
        [string]
        $ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )

    ($User = try 
             {
                (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerName Win32_ComputerSystem | 
                Select-Object -ExpandProperty username).trimstart("NG\")
             } 
             catch 
             {
                 'User not detected'
                 break
             }
    )

    ($BootStart = ((get-date) - (Get-CimInstance win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $ComputerName).LastBootUpTime).Days)
    
    If ($user -NE $null) 
    { 
        ($Date1  = Get-date)
        ($SP     = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $ComputerName -FilterHashTable @{
                                                            LogName   = 'Security'
                                                            ID        = '5379'
                                                            Data      = $User
                                                            StartTime = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-1))
                                                        })

        ($Date2 = (
                    $SP | 
                    select -first 1
                 ).timecreated)

        ($USERLOGTIME = ($Date1-$Date2).hours.tostring('N2'))
    }
    else
    {
        'No user'
        break
    }

    "Computer Name: $Computername
    ---USER---
    Name:          $User
    Log in Time    $USERLOGTIME
    Boot start     $BootStart days ago"

    $ComputerName | 
    ForEach-Object {
        if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $ComputerName -Count 1 -Quiet)
        {Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName}
        else 
        {Write-Warning -Message 'Computer is Unreachable or Offline'}    
    } 

    $UserMessage = '
    WARNING!
        This will READ LIST of computers in: 
        \\ou\ouor-groups\Desktop_Support\SD\Kiosks\kiosknames.txt 
    Type CONTINUE to proceed'
    $Continue = Read-Host $UserMessage 

    if ($Continue -eq 'CONTINUE')
    {
        Get-Content '\\ou\ouor-groups\Desktop Support\SD\Kiosks\kiosknames.txt' | 
        foreach {
            {start-job -Name $PSItem -ScriptBlock ${Function:get-kioskinfo} -ArgumentList $PSItem}

            [pscustomobject]@{ 
                                Name                        = $ComputerName
                                User                        = $User
                                'User Log in time in hours' = $USERLOGTIME
                                'BootStart days ago'        = $BootStart
                             } 
        } | 
        Export-Csv -path "$PWD\$ComputerName.csv" -Append 
    } 
}
```